# How to assign a field inside a nested record in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I'm quite the noob on COBOL i bought myself one of those "for dummies" type book but it lacks some depth.

I'm trying to assign and retrieve the value of a field from a nested record. I'm trying per my book suggested, this :

```
 WRITE REPORT-LINE FROM DATE OF HEADER
    AFTER ADVANCING PAGE.
 WRITE REPORT-LINE FROM INSTITUTION OF HEADER
    AFTER 1.
 WRITE REPORT-LINE FROM BRANCH OF HEADER
    AFTER 1.
 WRITE REPORT-LINE FROM DIVISION OF HEADER
    AFTER 1.
 WRITE REPORT-LINE FROM FILLER-LINE
```

The layout for my header is this one:

```
01  HEADER.
    02  DATE.
        03  O-MONTH                   PIC ZZ.
        03  FILLER                    PIC X(01) VALUE '/'.
        03  O-DAY                     PIC 99.
        03  FILLER                    PIC X(01) VALUE '/'.
        03  O-YEAR                    PIC 99.
        03  FILLER                    PIC X(116) VALUE SPACES.
        03  PAGE                      PIC A(4) VALUE 'PAGE'.
        03  FILLER                    PIC X(1) VALUE SPACE.
```

So basically my question is, How for example will I access 0-DAY field of the record DATE from HEADER?

Both for assignment and retrieval. Will it be something like:

```
MOVE 21 TO 0-DAY OF DATE OF HEADER.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly avoid data-names which are "words". DATE for instance is a word, SOMETHNG-DATE or DATE-SOMETHING are not.

`DATE` itself is a `Reserved Word` in COBOL, so I think it unlikely that your example will compile. A word like `HEADER` could easily become reserved in the future (although these days the standards committee try to avoid that).

HEADER is a group-item. DATE is a group item. The other fields are elementary items. We don't regard structures such as this as "nested", just as group-items which must contain at least one elementary item.

The only time you need to use OF/IN is when there are non-unique names (which you should avoid).

So:

```
MOVE 21 TO 0-DAY
```

Will work, as long as 0-DAY is not a duplicate name. The syntax you showed will also work, but why add all the extra for no point, it is just increasing the possibility of a typo, and making the next reader think that your program has non-unique names.

Try to avoid full-stops/periods in the PROCEDURE DIVISION except for those which are necessary (after the PROCEDURE DIVISION header, before a paragraph/SECTION after a paragraph/SECTION label, before the end of the program).

Comment: Thanks, will definitely follow your advise.